# Jenkins checkout into a user defined directory

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

My project has 3 submodules in GitLab, which are all needed to build my project. I want to create independent pipelines in Jenkins to monitor and pull when a merge request is open.

If I create individual pipelines, Jenkins will create a new folder with the name of the pipeline project like so: "jenkins_home/workspace/submodule1", "jenkins_home/workspace/submodule2", "jenkins_home/workspace/submodule3".
Is it possible to specify the directory where I want to checkout each submodule? As in, checkout all into "jenkins_home/workspace/common_folder", where common_folder will contain submodule1, submodule2 and submodule3.

P.S. I tried `bat 'cd common_folder'`, but the cd command just hangs and never executes.
Also tried `dir (**subdir**){}` which just creats a new directory inside the submodule pipeline directory: "jenkins_home/workspace/submodule1/**subdir**/code_from_git".

---

#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }

```
environment {
    gbuild = 'true'
    DB_ENGINE = 'sqlite'
}
options{
    skipDefaultCheckout()
}

stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            script {
                checkout([
```

**HERE, need to checkout into a custom folder and not the workspace**

```
                    $class: 'GitSCM', 
                    branches: scm.branches,
                    extensions: scm.extensions + [
                        [$class: 'GitLFSPull'],
                        [$class: 'CleanCheckout']
                    ], 
                userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
                ])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are doing dir is the correct approach or you can create separate pipelines.

> Jenkins works  on master slave configuration and the pipeline you create creates the same name folder in workspace on master server which is then created to slave server when you run the pipelines for the first time, once the pipeline runs and checkout the code on slave server it is then pushed to your master server.

I hope the answer explained you the working principle.

Comment: Yes I know that's the principal. I already tested dir(SUBDIRECOTRY), and as mentioned, it creates a subdirectory (ie creating another layer inside the same name folder in the workspace) as in "workspace\pipeline_folder_same_name\SUBDIRECOTRY\code_from_git.

That is not what I need. I want to specify the place where the same name folder will be created (the pipeline folder). As in, instead of creating the **pipeline_folder_same_name** inside workspace, I want to create it in another folder: workspace\my_new_folder\ **pipeline_folder_same_name** .

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for projects with subprojects, where you want to track each subproject for any merge requests and need all the subprojects to build is: use an independent pipeline.

Additional comment: as there is no admin access on the server pc this might be limiting my capabilities to execute some simple commands, this solution might not be correct for you.

As my cmd commands in the pipeline were not executing and keeping the whole pipeline from running, and I was not able to change the location of the project from **workspace** to a desired location, I created 2 extra pipelines.

First pipeline is there to listen to webhooks from GitLab and pull the branch in the merge request (also verifying if its a merge request, if so its going to take the branch being merged, if not it will take the master branch):

```
stage('Checkout'){
     steps{
       script{
           if(env.gitlabActionType == 'Merge')
           {
              checkout([
                   $class: 'GitSCM'
                   branches: [[name: "${env.gitlabSourceBranch}"]]
              ])
            }
            else
            {
              checkout([
                   $class: 'GitSCM'
                   branches: master
              ])
            }
       }
     } 
 }
```

Second pipeline to copy the checkouted files into the desired location. For this step I made a freestyle project, where i execute a windows batch command to `xcopy CheckedoutDir DesiredDestination`.

The second pipeline has **Build Trigger** to build after first pipeline is built stable. It also has a **Trigger/call builds on other projects** to trigger the main pipeline that does the building and unit testing.